# Can I queue a Tumblr post to post next year?

Tags: tumblr

I'm going out of town near the end of the year, and I'd like for Tumblr to make a few posts for me while I'm gone. Can I queue a Tumblr post to post next year?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You wouldn't be able to use your queue for this, but you could set publish date/times for the posts you'd like Tumblr to post for you next year.

You'll need to select "Publish on" where it normally says "Publish now" and you'll need to specify a date/time as well.

[image: Tumblr Post Queued For Next Year]